# asp.net setting up subdomain on localhost

Tags: asp.net

I added the following entries in the HOSTS file.

127.0.0.1  abc.localhost.com
127.0.0.1  xyz.localhost.com

Using the VS2010 ASP.NET Development server I am unable to run or execute the website.

When browsing http://localhost:2687/TestProject/ it shows up the default.aspx page. But when accessing http://abc.localhost:2687/TestProject/ it shows a website cannot be found page.

Is there anything else to be done when setting up subdomain on localhost.

**EDIT**: To make this work I removed the .com and in IE-->Connections-->LAN uncheck everything. Subdomains with port works are correctly getting forwarded. Nothing else need to be configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious mistake is that in your hosts file you have abc.localhost.com, whereas you are browsing to http://abc.localhost/folder

Not the same thing.

Not sure this will work as you intend anyhow. I would also recommend IIS Express, part of WebMatrix, which I think is still in beta, or just use IIS. IIS 7+ on Vista, W7, Server 2008 is all really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. What did the trick was to set proxy settings to default.

Answer (score 2):

Use IIS or IIS express, rather than Cassini. (For several reasons, which you can google or look for on stackoverflow)

With the IIS you can easily add a hostheader entry to you webapplication with just 2 clicks.

Be aware, that you are assigning both a Url and a port.
So adding abc.localhost won't allow you to browse abc.localhost2687, just the default port (80). If you also want to browse to abc.localhost:2687 you need to a a hostheader entry according to that that Url and port.

This screenshot shows you the dialog to add hostheaders (the picture is from IIS 6, but in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 it looks very similar)

[image]