# asp.net mvc3 setting up subdomain on localhost

Tags: asp.net, testing, localhost, subdomain

I'm trying to do something similar to this post [asp.net setting up subdomain on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745517/asp-net-setting-up-subdomain-on-localhost)

I have the following added to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       test1.localhost
127.0.0.1       test2.localhost
```

I have unchecked everyting under LAN connections as mentioned in the post.  HOwever, from within VS 2010, running the application and going to localhost:7217 works. But going to test1.localhost still falls over with an error 'IE could not find test1.localhost'

The application is based on MVC3, so not sure if I should be adding routing related changes to global.ascx. Is this required? What else should I be doing for this to work?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried going to test1.localhost:7217?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either. Same error as before.  Do I need to make the routing change in global.acsx before this will work?

Comment: why not just make up some domains and add those instead? `127.0.0.1    test1.mytestwebsite.co.uk`

Comment: Did you add the hostname to the site in IIS?

Comment: Are you using full IIS as development server or are you using the built in one\iis express? (levelnis beat me to it :))

Comment: Roysvork, yes I am using the built-in one.  Will this not work? DO I have to deploy to the 'proper' IIS server first?